# let A, B and C be subspaces of V . Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be subspaces of $V$. Which of the following statements are true?

(a) $$A \cap (B + C) = (A \cap B) + (A \cap C)$$
(b) $$A \cap (B + C) \subset (A \cap B) + (A \cap C)$$
(c) $$A \cap (B + C) \supset (A \cap B) + (A \cap C)$$

My attempt: 
             I was drawing the Venn diagram. From Venn diagram I concluded  that
            $$A \cap (B + C) = (A \cap B) + (A \cap C)$$  is true ..

Is my answer is correct or not, im not sure  about my answer help Me..

Comment: How can you represent $A + B$ in a Venn diagram?  Note that $A + B$ does **not** mean the same thing as $A \cup B$.

Comment: A Venn diagram cannot make the difference between a mere  subset and subspace.

Comment: ok i was thinking that A +B =A∪B @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is only choice c which is correct.

As a counter-example for the other two, consider the following:

- $V = \Bbb R^2$
- $A$ is the span of the vector $(1,1)$
- $B$ is the $x$-axis
- $C$ is the $y$-axis

Comment: im not getting ,,,can u elaborate,,as i was  taking x=1 and y = 1 that mean      
  B+C = 2 and  A is span as i can take 2(1,1) = (2,2)  here  A ∩ (B + C) =2 @Omnomnomnom...

Comment: The "$x$-axis" is an informal way to refer to the span of the vector $(1,0)$, which is a subspace of $V$.  So $B$ is the span of $(1,0)$ and $C$ is the span of $(0,1)$.

Comment: Note that the question says "$B$ and $C$ are subspaces of $V$".  In what way could $B = C = 1$ make *any sense at all*?

Comment: it was my mistakes ,,,,,,i was looking V= R  so i was simply taking  x= 1 ...Thanks  a lots ,,i got it now @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 1):

Consider the subspaces $B=\langle\, u\,\rangle$, $C=\langle\, v\,\rangle$, $A=\langle\, u+v\,\rangle$.

Then $A\cap(B+C)=A$, but $A\cap B=A\cap C=\{\,0\,\}$.

Comment: thanks@ bernard,,

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to make conclusions about subspace operations solely on the set theoretic properties such as De Morgan rules, as the operations on subspaces are sometimes defined differently.

Let $M, N \leq V$. The usual definition of $M+N$ is $M+N = [M\cup N]$, where $[S]$ is the linear span of a set $S \subseteq V$.

Proof for $(c)$:

Since the intersection of subspaces is a subspace, and a span of a set is a subspace, $A\cap[B\cup C]$ is a subspace and hence equal to its span:

$A\cap[B\cup C] = \left[A\cap[B\cup C]\right] \supseteq \left[A\cap(B\cup C)\right] = \left[(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\right] = (A\cap B) + (A\cap C)$

Comment: Thanks,,,,,, this one is beautiful  @mechanodroid